# Why does my Nest method in controller create an index?

Tags: c#, asp.net, elasticsearch, model-view-controller, nest

i am using net 6.0.1 with asp.net mvc.

```
var node = new Uri("http://localhost:9200");
        var setting = new ConnectionSettings(node);
        var client = new ElasticClient(setting);

        var news = new News
        {
            NewsTitle = "TestTitle"
            
        };

        client.Index(news, idx => idx.Index("NewsTitle"));
        var response = client.Get<News>(1, idx => idx.Index("NewsTitle"));
```

ElasticSearch is installed and running but when I try to run these lines of code then it does nothing. No index is created.

Comment: You are making a Request and then parsing the Response.  So depending on the request parameters determine the number of NewTitle responses you are getting. You may only be getting one response of one index.  You may need to change the request to get more results.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things to consider

1. `client.Index(news, idx => idx.Index("NewsTitle"));` doesn't check the response of the index document request.

   It's a good idea to check the response to see if it succeeded - NEST
   has a convenient `.IsValid` property on all responses that has
   semantics for considering if the response is valid
2. `var response = client.Get<News>(1, idx => idx.Index("NewsTitle"));` attempts to get a document from the `"NewsTitle"` index with an id of `1`, but the document just indexed does not have an id, so Elasticsearch will generate a random one when it indexes the document.

   NEST has a convention where if the POCO to index has an `Id` property, it will use this as the id of the document. So, if `News` class is modified to contain an `int` Id property, and the instance indexed is assigned an Id property value of `1`, the get request will return the indexed document.